# ResultSet error "Cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, mysql, jframe, prepared-statements, mysqlconnector

Recientemente trabajo con un código que se conecta a una base de datos en mysql. Su funcionalidad es insertar datos a la tabla previamente creada y después con un botón darle funcionalidad de vaciar TxtField en Jframe para volver a llenar.

El error me lo muestra solo en el ResultSet con la opción de crear clase y también cabe mencionar que he creado el Statement previamente.

Les agradezco ayuda.
SALUDOS¡

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Connection conectar = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            conectar = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/name","root","");
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String idContribuyente=this.jTextField4.getText();
        try{
            Statement s=(Statement) conectar.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("query");
```

Answer (score 0):

La sentencia

```
ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("query");
```

No va a funcionar, `"query"` no es SQL válido, esa string debería ser algo como `"select <columnas> from..."`

Comment: Lo se de ante mano @Pablo Lozano, eso de query lo hice unicamente para evitar escribir toda la sentencia y realmente en esa parte no tengo problema, el problema lo tengo como ya loa había puesto en el "ResultSet" al tratar de recuperar los campos vacíos. La sentencia original es esta: ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT idContribuyente, nombre, rfc, timbre, fechaContribucion, foto, ruta FROM datos WHERE idContribuyente'"+idContribuyente+ "'");
                if(rs.next()){

Comment: El problema para resolver tu error es que no especificas si es una excepción, un error de compilación, en qué línea ocurre... así que he ido por lo único que se ve mal a primera vista. Quizá deberías añadir más datos sobre el error: si es una excepción, añade la traza, por ejemplo

Comment: Tienes razón Pablo el error realmente es que no me reconóce el ResultSet solamente y me da la opción de añadir el ResultSet como clase.

Answer (score 0):

El método [executeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html#executing_queries) retorna un objeto ResultSet definido por la consulta  que defines como parametro:

```
 //ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("query");
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Por lo tanto `query` debe ser una variable que contenga tu consulta, por ejemplo:

```
 String query = "select * from basededatos.tabla";
 ...
 ...
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Revisa el ejemplo de la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html#executing_queries).